# marker.setDraggable(false) throws an exception in main.js in API Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have this code in JavaScript:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'dragend',x(mark));

function x(mark)
{
    mark.setDraggable(false);
}
```

When I move a marker to another position it throws this exception in main.js:

```
SCRIPT5007:Can not get value of property 'apply': the object is null or undefined     
main.js, Línea 23 Carácter 104
```

It only happens in IE, in Chrome and Firefox the code runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'dragend', x)`;

Comment: I've changed but the event's never call x method :(

Answer (score 0):

You could make the marker a global variable:

```
var mark;

function initialize() {
    mark = new google.maps.Marker() //Set up marker here
    google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'dragend', doMarkStuff);
}

function doMarkStuff() {
    mark.setDraggable(false);
}
```

Assuming that you initialize your map and marker in the initialize function.